# Alert on change of select option using jQuery in console

Tags: html, jquery, select-options

I have a page having select option, where it will show alert box when option is changed:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <script>
    $("select").change(function() {
      alert('Hi');
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I clicked manually and changed the option and I got alert as expected.

Now I want to change the option using jquery & console. So, when I add the below code to console it changes the option but this time there is no alert. Why so?

```
$('select option').filter('[value=saab]').prop('selected',true)
```

Comment: You can add `.trigger("change")` this will trigger the change event.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen in console? As I cannot change anything in the html page.

Comment: You donøt need to change the html page, try `$('select option').filter('[value=saab]').prop('selected',true).trigger("change")`